# Anti .gitignore - for files which will be in GIT, but not in actual directory. How?

Tags: git, gitignore

I have several .htaccess files for server project version, but delete them for local project version, because I don't need this protection locally and don't want to setup correct paths to keys files to make them work.

Is it possible to keep .htaccess files in GIT, but don't keep them in working directory?
Something like anti-.gitignore approach.

Comment: Why don't you simply use `AllowOverride None` in your apache setup so they are ignored.

Comment: AD7six, Thank you for idea, I will try this too, but I am still interested if such (or some similar problem) can be solved with GIT.

Comment: The  thing to search for (i.e. this is a duplicate) is `git update-index --assume-unchanged` or `git update-index --ignore-missing` - I wouldn't recommend that route though.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to keep `.htaccess` files in GIT, but don't keep them in working directory?

Yes: don't version `.htaccess`.
Version a `.htaccess.server` and a `.htaccess.local`

Then version a script which can detect which environment (server or local) it is executed, and copy the right file as a private `.htaccess` (actually declared in .gitignored, meaning always ignored by Git, never tracked)

This is a [content filter driver approach](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes#_code_filter_code), and you can see an example in 
"[Git ignore changes to committed file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51568815/6309)".

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNZTT.png]
<sup>(image from "[Customizing Git - Git Attributes](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#Keyword-Expansion)", from "[Pro Git book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/)")</sup>