# A file needs to be in git global repo and it should be ignored by git

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

i have a file which has to be in everyone's machine as well as in git global repository, then i have to edit the file and it should be ignored by git.

i have tried using:
1. git rm --cached 
2. git update-index --assume-unchanged 
3. git update-index --skip-worktree

Comment: A question, when that file is edited in your system you want it to be changed in remote/global repo as well. If not, why don't you try to commit it and add it to ignore later

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git ignore changes to committed file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27839263/git-ignore-changes-to-committed-file)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+add+file+ignore+changes

Comment: @SarathDamaraju, i don't want it to be changed in global repo.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not store files.  Git stores *commits*.  It's true that commits store files—so you can *get* Git to store files—but what Git stores are *commits*.

If you want to store a file in Git, you must put it in some set of commits.  It's that simple.  Make a new commit that has the file in it, and you're done: the file is now stored in the Git repository.

If you want to *get* that one *particular* file *from* that one particular commit, into your work-tree, as an *untracked* file: well, that's another question entirely.  There are a bunch of ways to do that, including the new Git 2.23-or-newer `git restore`.  One way that works in most varieties of Git that are out there right now is to use `git show`:

```
git show <commit-specifier>:<path>
```

shows the contents of the given path-within-commit to its standard output.

You can have all of your users do:

```
git show your-tag:path/to/file.ext > file.ext
```

or:

```
git show your-branch:path/to/file.ext > file.ext
```

or:

```
git show <raw hash ID>:path/to/file.ext > file.ext
```

to extract the one specific file named `path/to/file.ext` from the one specific commit tagged by `your-tag` or named by `your-branch` or given by its raw hash ID, into their work-trees under the name `file.ext`.

Note that if anyone ever *checks out* this one specific commit, in any way, that file will appear in `path/to/file.ext` in their work-tree and be *tracked* (in the index), because it was in that one commit.  Checking out some *other* commit that *does not* have the file in it will remove `path/to/file.ext` from the index and from their work-tree, because that *other* commit *does not* have the file.  That's why we use a trick like `git show` to *view* the file without copying it into the index.