# How to prevent anyone from modifying a tracked file in git?

Tags: git

There are multiple questions and answers on SO that explain how to add a file to a git repository and ignore all future changes to it. This is usually accomplished by `update-index` command accompanied with one of the `assume-unchanged` or `skip-worktree` options.

However, these commands have effect only on the local scope. The changes I will perform on a given file will indeed be ignored and won't be shown in the list of staged files. What I want is to prevent anyone from modifying a given file. For example I might add a .properties file that will serve as a template for users that will clone my repository and I don't want it to be modifiable. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: Use a server-side hook to reject changes to the file(s) in question.  See the accepted answer to this question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553551/how-can-i-mark-a-committed-file-as-read-only-in-git

Comment: In addition to this, play dirty and set the file permissions so only you can write to it but anyone can read it.

Comment: Usually people do this by having a file called something like `settings-example.properties` with instructions inside to copy to `settings.properties` during configuration. `settings-example.properties` is checked in, while `settings.properties` is included in the project's `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For example I might add a .properties file that will serve as a template for users that will clone my repository and I don't want it to be modifiable. How could this be accomplished?

Other people's repositories are theirs. You control what happens in your repositories.  They control what happens in theirs.

You can vet what gets pushed to your repositories with a pre-receive hook that scans the inbound commits for things you don't want, for instance:

```
#!/bin/sh -f
while read old new ref; do news="$news $new"; done
git rev-list $news --not --all | while read check; do
     [[ `git rev-parse $check:path/to/it` = `git rev-parse master:path/to/it` ]] \
     || { echo "path/to/it altered in commit $check; refusing push"; rc=1; }
done
exit $rc
```