# How to Avoid Committing Tokens in GIT

Tags: git, token, config, commit

I have been doing back-flips to avoid committing API tokens into my git repositories. Often I have been failing. Despite my best efforts I cannot find any tool or builtin command to prevent the accidental commit of my tokens prompting rather embarrassing second commits and token refreshes.

I am wondering if anyone has found a good solution to my problem?

I mostly make a config.yaml or config.json that I set basic parameters in. I commit this initial schema and try to avoid ever committing to it again sometimes with awkward merges. While testing or writing my code in another branch I fill in the placeholders with actual tokens. Unfortunately, I accidentally commit them sometimes.

Is there anyway to stage a master copy in git for a file that requires a special git add that a normal `git commit -am . . .` wouldn't trigger?

Comment: Note that adding another commit where the tokens are removed does not prevent anyone from looking at them in earlier commits.

Comment: Thank you, I am aware of that and I do refresh my tokens to generate a new one when I realize that I have accidentally committed them: ***"prompting rather embarrassing second commits and token refreshes."***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I mark a committed file as read-only in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553551/how-can-i-mark-a-committed-file-as-read-only-in-git)

Comment: I store my app's API keys in environment variables, and then access the values in code. For example in Rails: `Rails.configuration.x.twitter_api_secret = ENV['TWITTER_API_SECRET']`. This is the same thing that Rails does by default with the SECRET_KEY_BASE variable in the `secrets.yml` file: `secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>`

Comment: @Aaron So you want to store in git a version of the file without the `secrets` in it? And prevent yourself from accidentally committing the file once you add the `secrets`?

Comment: @PeterReid Yep, like a lock within git

Answer (score 1):

There's two potential solutions to this problem:

**Option A**
**Empty out the secrets** from your `config.yml` then:

```
git add config.yml
git commit -m "Added config.yml"
```

Open your `.gitignore` file in your favourite text editor and add line

```
config.yml
```

You can now safely put your `secrets` back into the file, and not be concerned about accidentally committing them to git.

The disadvantage to this is that you have to run this procedure any time you want to update the remote file.

**Option 2**
This option involves maintaining a second `config.yml.example`. As before add `config.yml` to your `.gitignore`. Keep the 'template' for the config as you would any other file in git.