# Cygwin Symlinks .lnk do not work after git clone

Tags: git, cygwin, symlink, git-clone

I've created a git repo with a symlink inside.
This symlik is created with cygwin.

```
cd ./bar && ln -s ../foo.md foo.md
```

Cygwin creats a foo.md.lnk file.
For now everything is okay.

```
foo.md -> ../foo.md
```

If I push the repo to GitLab and clone it somewhere else
the symlink is just a textfile.

```
foo.md.lnk*
```

The problem is that: 
https://www.cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#pathnames-symlinks

All of the above four symlink types are recognized and used as symlinks under  all circumstances. However, if the default plain file symlink type is lacking   its DOS SYSTEM bit, or if the shortcut file is lacking the DOS READONLY   attribute, they are not recognized as symlink.

And git does not support this READONLY attribute.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27554044/5190206

Comment: It is interesting that this solution worked for you. Interested in this question, I tried to reproduce your situation and if I create the link using Windows's Create Shortcut functionality, your solution works to make that link clickable in Windows Explorer again. But if I create the link using `ln -s`, it is never clickable in Windows and it works fine in Cygwin after checking it out from Git, without using `chmod`. So I'm wondering how you are configured for this situation to arise as you describe. What version of Cygwin? OS? What does your `CYGWIN` variable say?

Comment: I Use winsymlinks in my cygwin. Under a Windows 7 Os. 
When creating the symlink in the cygwin shell and than push it to the remote you should see ther a .lnk file. After cloning it the link is handled as text file.
https://github.com/ElJulio/cygwin_symlink if you clone this the symlink should not work until the chmod.

Answer (score 0):

Create a post-checkout hook under `.git/hooks/post-checkout`

```
#! /bin/sh
# post-checkout hook to make all lnk files read-only
find -type f -iname "*.lnk" -exec chmod -w {} \;
```