# Commit files to git but disallow changes after

Tags: git, github

I have some IDE run configuration files that I'd like to commit to my git repository so our team can share them. Unfortunately, they may be modified later to include private or secure system properties. Therefore, I would also like to disallow them to change once committed. The initially committed files will not include any private, secure, or sensitive information.

Is it possible to commit files to a repository permanently, and permanently disallow them to be modified? I am aware of temporary ways to do this on a local clone (such as untracking the file) but I'd like to always have them in the remote, just instruct git to never track any changes, even for new clones.

Comment: The way to solve this is to add files that contain sensitive information to `.gitignore` so they don't even get tried to be committed. Then, you could start using merge requests to cross verify changes.

Comment: @DanielW. Can you explain that further? I already tried to commit them and then add them to .gitignore. Once files are committed they are tracked, though. .gitignore has no effect at that point.

Comment: Private and secure data doesn't belong in Git at all.

Comment: If a file is tracked, then not checking in changes in that file that need to be not checked in is up to the individual. You can't magically enforce this from above; people have to use their brains.

Comment: @chepner Hence the question

Comment: @matt There are ways to set a file as untracked after checking it out from the repo. So far, I only see this applying temporarily to the local clone. It stands to reason that since you can set files as untracked, there would be a way to do so in the remote as well.

Comment: If the tool in question puts sensitive and non-sensitive information in the same file, then you shouldn't use git at this point. Besides, either put the file containing sensitive information in `.gitignore` or make the repository `readonly` by changing the permissions accordingly.

Comment: Split your configuration into two sets of files. One for the defaults, one for local overrides. Commit the default files. Add the local override files to .gitignore. Disallow changes to the default file during your review process or use a [Git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Comment: @Schwern Yeah that would make sense and if the IDE supported it I would do that. If git can't support this then that's fine and I'll figure something out. But I'm just wondering if I overlooked something in git's capability. Sounds like not, so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to commit files to a repository permanently, and permanently disallow them to be modified?

Sort of.

Here are some options which "sort of" achieve what you want:

1. Setup a commit hook that developers use locally to prevent accidentally committing that file.
2. Setup a [Code Owner rule in GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) for that specific file in conjunction with Branch Protection, so that only specific people can allow a PR to be completed if that file is modified.

You can't force #1. You can force #2 but that wouldn't stop developers from accidentally pushing sensitive data into the shared repo. But it would at least prevent it from getting merged in without certain people approving it. Perhaps some combination of these would be best.

**Alternative?**

Another approach would be to try to avoid this completely. One way to achieve it is to have an overlay/transform file that is untracked and can be in the .gitignore file. Then you can have:

```
my-file-base # checked in and tracked like a normal file
my-file-override # Listed in .gitignore
```

And the "thing" that reads that file can check for the existence of `my-file-override` and if it's there, it can modify `my-file-base` with the overrides, and/or add in the new stuff. Each developer can set that up as desired.

**Side Note:**

Just a word of caution, from the [Git documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-update-index#_notes) regarding `update-index`:

> Users often try to use the assume-unchanged and skip-worktree bits to tell Git to ignore changes to files that are tracked. This does not work as expected, since Git may still check working tree files against the index when performing certain operations. **In general, Git does not provide a way to ignore changes to tracked files, so alternate solutions are recommended.**

Comment: Thanks! These are all valid options and I hadn't considered #2 and #3.

Comment: @ScottShipp #2 is a client side Git Hook, and #3 is kind of like a server side Git Hook at the PR level, but you are at the mercy of what GitHub allows you to do on their servers, which, fortunately is probably sufficient here.

Comment: The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) specifically instructs against using `git update-index` for this purpose and explains what you should do instead.

Comment: @bk2204 Thx for pointing that out. I removed that option. The alternative Git suggests is exactly what I proposed though. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#ignore-tracked-files) covers the case of wanting ignore changes to tracked files, and explains why it's not possible with Git.

Fortunately, it is easy to handle the configuration case you want to handle.  Take the actual configuration file and ignore it.  Then, check in a template or set of defaults, which uses can customize themselves or use a script to set up by copying into the actual configuration file location.  This is the recommended approach for most of these cases.

If you're using GitHub Enterprise Server, you can restrict pushing of certain files with a pre-receive hook, but this capability isn't available on github.com.  Regardless, it's better to avoid the need for the hook if possible by using the recommended approach.