# In Kotlin, how can one unit test that a data class, sealed class, or class field are not changed?

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin

Basically we might have some data like so

```
open class RealmCart : RealmObject() {
    @PrimaryKey
    var _id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
    var items: RealmList<RealmCartItem> = RealmList()
    var discountCode: String? = null
    var userId: String = ""
}
```

And we do not want people editing these by mistake. We have some failsafe like code owners, labels in the repo, but we also want to have a unit test that can also prevent a merge if the data is changed in any way (add, change, or remove data). Basically, we do not want any accidents, and people are not perfect.

What is the best way to go about such a thing?

Comment: just check if a class with that name and these attributes exist with reflection?

Comment: I am not quite sure how to do that, do you have an example somewhere?

Comment: Considering that people are not perfect, how will you ensure that the code written to "protect" this code won't also be changed? And the code made to protect that code, and so on? The only way to do this properly is to lock your important branches and have a knowledgeable person review pull requests before they are merged.

Comment: The idea is that an accident is less likely to happen. If someone changes the original class, the unit test should fail, and then they might be alerted that they will need to change the unit test as well. It is hard to make that mistake twice.

We do have code owners, and even a tagging system that will tag PR's, but it is an extra line of defense for carelessness.

I basically just want to create a spec for the objects to conform to. Not sure how to do this.

I am mostly worried about fields being added to the object, without someone realizing.

Comment: How would you know that the class is perfectly designed in the first place such that you now need to lock its source code? Unit tests on the behavior. So if the class changes in a way that is problematic, the unit tests would catch it anyway. Maybe the class can be improved without changing the outputs, and so your proposed test would prevent that.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27553551/how-can-i-mark-a-committed-file-as-read-only-in-git

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

I created an extension function for my data models

```
fun RealmObject.testDeclaredFields(): List<String> {
    val fields = this::class.java.fields.map { it.name }
    return this::class.java.declaredFields
        .map { it.name }
        .filterNot { fields.contains(it) }
        .sorted()
}
```

Basically this just gets the data model fields, excluding things like companion objects.

Then I was able to create a test simply like

```
class RealmMessageTest {

    @Test
    fun `RealmMessage fields match spec`() {
        val item = RealmMessage().testDeclaredFields()
        assertContentEquals(item, fieldSpec)
    }

    private val fieldSpec = listOf(
        "_id",
        "acknowledgeStatusValue",
        "body",
        "completed",
        "createdAt",
        "deliveryStatusValue",
        "from",
        "meta",
        "organizationId",
        "platforms",
        "threadId",
        "title"
    ).sorted()
}
```

Why do this? Sometimes when someone is making changes carelessly, they will not realize that they have added a field, changed a field, or removed an important field in a data model that is sync'd to the backend. This does not prevent the developer from changing it, but given that they need to now change it in two places, they will be more cognizant whether they *need* to make this change or not.

I noticed a lot of people questioned why you would need to do this. My answer is that, I work in a very large repo where newer developers edit this without a second thought. This is just to make them more cognizant of changes to these important models, before they break develop. There are code owners for the repo, but they may not always see these changes. It is just an extra precaution.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a mechanism like `githooks` to prevent the editing of certain files from being committed?
I'm not familiar with `githooks`, so I can't show you exactly how to do it, but I think it would be good to prevent commits and inform the developer of the situation with an error message.