# Git - Ignore only new versions of the file

Tags: git

I want to keep a few files in the repository but prevent updating them. Unfortunately looks till the file is at the repository even if it matches gitignore pattern can be updated. I want to commit (final) a version of that file(s) but prevent any update. Anyone can have his own version of that files but can't commit them and they should be ignored during commit. Is that possible?

Comment: No, it is not. Git does not support this. The typical way to do this, however, is to commit a template, with a different file name, kinda like `web.config.template`, and then ignore the real deal, `web.config`. Then each person would, themselves, have to make a copy of the file from the template to the actual file, make their own local modifications, and these would not be committed, nor would their copy of the file be updated from the template except if they consciously do so themselves. This allow you to update the template without disturbing anyone.

Comment: `.gitignore` only controls whether untracked files should be reported by `git status`, or added by `git add`, etc. It has *no* effect on tracked files at all.

Comment: Here's a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27553551/184546), one of the answers is @LasseV.Karlsen's suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Anyone can have his own version of that files but can't commit them and they should be ignored during commit. Is that possible?

Not in Git itself.

You can probably get pretty close to what you want, with some combination of:

1. A [pre-commit hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) can be used to make sure certain custom conditions are met. You could create a condition that the file is not in the list of changes for the commit. You then could *ask* your collaborators to please use that commit hook. Note they could choose not to if they wish.
2. Do you use a Git SCM tool? Many tools offer policies you could associate to a branch. You could use a gated checkin or branch policy to prevent completing a Pull Request that modifies specific files.